# Powershell script to read and split filename from a folder

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell. I want to read names of each file in a folder for eg. `900_CA_2022.pdf`, remove the `_` from the filename and create a new text file which has name `900CA2022900_CA_2022.txt`

Basically, I want to remove the `_` from the extension-less file name, append the latter as-is, and use a new extension, `.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is use the same **name of source file** + **.txt** for create the text files without doing much damage to the source filenames.

E.g.
**900_CA_2022.pdf** -----> **900_CA_2022.pdf.txt**

## My alternative solution

**Initial files**
[image: initial files]

**Script Code**

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "./*.pdf" -Recurse -Force
$files | ForEach-Object{
    New-Item -Path "$($_ | Split-Path)/$($_ | Split-Path -Leaf).txt" -Force
}
```

**Result files**
[image: result files]
[image: result files gui]

Answer (score 0):

Update:

- The stated requirements are unusual, but the next section provides a solution to address them.
- The fact that you later accepted Joma's answer indicates that simply appending `.txt` to each input file name is what you actually needed; this is most easily accomplished as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | New-Item -Path { $_.FullName + '.txt' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

**Important**: All solutions below create the new files in the *current* directory. If needed, construct the target file path with an explicit directory path, using [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path), e.g.:
`Join-Path C:\target (($_.BaseName -replace '_') + $_.BaseName + '.txt')`

---

To **create *new, empty files*** whose *names* should be derived from the input files, use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | 
  New-Item -Path { ($_.BaseName -replace '_') + $_.BaseName + '.txt' } -WhatIf
```

Note: If the target file exists, an error occurs. If you add `-Force`, the existing file is *truncated* instead - use with caution.

- `$_.BaseName` is the input file's name *without the extension*.
- `-replace '_'` removes all `_` chars. from it.

---

To **create *new files*** whose *names* should be derived from the input files ***and fill them***, use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    # Construct the new file path.
    $newFilePath = ($_.BaseName -replace '_') + $_.BaseName + '.txt'
    # Create and fill the new file.
    # `>` acts like Out-File. To control the encoding, use 
    # something like `| Out-File -Encoding utf8 $newFilePath` instead.
    "content for $newFilePath" > $newFilePath
  }
```

Note that `>` / [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (for string data) all quietly replace the contents of an existing target file.